# Select groups given a condition in a variable sql

Tags: sql, group-by

I must do a query where I select those groups, given by de concatenation between `sample` and `serial` that could be defined as `household`, where at least one in the variable  `bplcountry = 1`

```
sample serial bplcountry
1      1      2
1      1      1
1      3      2
2      1      2
2      2      2
2      3      2
3      1      2
3      3      2
3      3      1
```

I have made some research but I'm very amateur on SQL. I get some hint like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM latinCensus
GROUP BY sample AND serial
HAVING COUNT(bplcountry NOT IN ('1') OR NULL) = 0
```

Also I got some idea in this way

```
SELECT *
FROM latinCensus
GROUP BY CONCAT(sample,serial) 
HAVING COUNT(bplcountry NOT IN ('1') OR NULL) = 0
```

I would expect something like this:

```
sample serial bplcountry
1      1      2
1      1      1
3      3      2
3      3      1
```

I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You want the pairs where bplcountry is 1.  You can use window functions:

```
select lc.*
from (select lc.*,
             sum(case when bplcountry = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by sample, serial) as cnt_1
      from latincensus lc
     ) lc
where cnt_1 > 0;
```

Or use `exists`:

```
select lc.*
from latincensus lc
where exists (select 1
              from latincensus lc2
              where lc2.sample = lc.sample and lc2.serial = lc.serial and
                    lc2.bplcountry = 1
             );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try and study I'll be back if something happens.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged your db, but something along these lines should work (can also be expressed using `joins`)

```
select sample, serial, bplcountry
from t
where (sample,serial) in (select sample,serial 
                          from t 
                          where bplcountry=1);
```